# Turing degree of Solomonoff semi-measure

Tags: computability, pr.probability, universal-turing-machines

We define the [Solomonoff semi-measure](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Algorithmic_probability#Discrete_Universal_A_Priori_Probability) $m$ on finite strings $x$ by

$$m(x) = \sum_{p: U(p) = x} 2^{-l(p)},$$

where $U$ is a universal [prefix Turing machine](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Algorithmic_complexity#Prefix_Turing_machine), $U(p) = x$ means $U$ outputs $x$ on input $p$, and $l(p)$ is the length of $p$.
What is the Turing degree of (computing the first $n$ digits of) $m(x)$?

Comment: Is "computing the first $n$ digits of" $m(x)$ (with $n$ as an input) known to $\hspace{1.89 in}$ be equivalent to computing $m(x)$? $\;$

Comment: We can certainly only ever compute a finite sequence of digits of $m(x)$, so the two mean the same thing

Comment: How does that follow? $\:$ (Consider the sequence of real numbers whose $m$-th entry is the limit of the sequence whose $n$-th term is 0.499999...[$t$ of them]...99999, where $t$ is the maximum of $n$ and the number of steps that $U(m)$ runs for.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Are you referring to this issue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number#Informal_definition_using_a_Turing_machine_as_example ? It looks like I should have used the "modern definition" rather than Minsky's.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from $ m (0) $ you can compute a version of Chaitin's $\Omega $. Moreover $ m (x) $ is left-c.e. uniformly in $ x $. So $ m $ has Turing degree $0'$.